# Inserting Images into SQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert an image into an SQL table (I know that it would be more efficient to store the images themselves in the web server, but I can't find code for that so if you know how to do that I'd love to hear how)
It's not throwing any errors but it's also not inserting the data into the table. Any help is welcome

upload_picture.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file_insert.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post" >
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputImage3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
        <p><label><input id="inputImage3" type="file" name="image" /></label></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="submit2" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="submit2" type="submit" value="insert image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

file_insert.php

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
session_start();
include("Web_Framework/database_connect.php");
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
if(!isset($file))
    {
      echo 'Please select an Image';
    }
    else
    {
    $image_check = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if($image_check==false)
        {
          echo 'Not a Valid Image';
        }
        else
        {
            $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $image_query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO pictures     (image, name, item_id) VALUES ('{$image}', '{$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']}', '{$id}')");
            header('location:Web_Framework/index.php');
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: why don't you insert the image path?

Comment: you are inserting the temp name. nothing more

Comment: I'm not sure if that would let multiple users view it from different machines, which is why I thought about inserting them into the web server (not the SQL database) but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to mix GET parameter and method post

Comment: *It's not throwing any errors* You never check for Errors. Where do you know there arn't errors

Answer (score 0):

> you should store only image-name into database, and upload file on server
>   using 
>   **move_uploaded_file() function**
>
> if you want to upload whole file on database then use
>   **base64_encode** function

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$data = base64_encode($data);
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO pictures (image, name, item_id) VALUES ('".$data."', '".$file_name."', $id)");
```